# Why should I use driver.find instead of wait.until in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

In Selenium, I can find an element by using `driver.find`, and by using the explicit wait `wait.until`. Explicit wait waits until the element is clickable, then it proceeds to the next step. Why should I use `driver.find` and risk timing out in case the element is for some reason not found, when I can just put `wait.until` everywhere? Is there a performance penalty or am I missing something?

Comment: If it's static element (you can find it in page source) then you should have no problem with `find_element` method. You need to use `wait` for dynamic elements. If to use `wait` for each element (even static) you'll just loose extra time in case of fail.

Comment: your expected condition will return the element if the condition is met (if using by locator the wait loop finds via locator) and the until will pass it along... so when using wait.until there's no need for driver.find... it'll either return the element, throw a timeout, or some other exception (stale element, click intercepted, etc...) https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By)